# Widget to show Data

Tags: orchardcms

I created a Deposit module. My main goal with this module is to save some data on the DB.

I already made my custom type (Deposit) with my custom part (DepositPart) and it worked like I expected.

This DepositPart save the name, currency, liquidity, month, and url on the database.
But now I want to make a simple widget with 3 combobox and a button.

On those combobox I have some static text where the user can choose from. When the user hit the button I want to make a query and return a list with some Deposits and show only the name and the liquidity.

What is the best way to achieved this?

Answer (score 0):

The best is creating your own controller.

For the part you have you can easily present as a widget adding some lines to migrations.

example:
(you can find more at this link: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-widget )

```
    public int UpdateFrom1()
    {
        // Create a new widget content type with our map
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("MapWidget", cfg => cfg
            .WithPart("MapPart")
            .WithPart("WidgetPart")
            .WithPart("CommonPart")
            .WithSetting("Stereotype", "Widget"));

        return 2;
    }
```

Note that you simple add WidgetPart and add stereotype "Widget" to a new Content Type that also has yourpart (in this example MapPart).

For the result you may use a controller.

Having more information about your part I can help you more.

Comment: After having a controller and a view, how can I add a Widget with them?

Comment: My widget needs to be on the homepage. The widgets should load with a view with 3 combobox and a button. The first combobox will have 4 options to choose from. The second one will have 2 options and the third will also have 2 options to choose.
It's only after choosing all the options on the combobox that I hit the button to execute the query based on the combobox options. So I think that I can't follow your instructions

Comment: It may work. Create your part so that has all combo you need. Wrap them in a form and post it to your controller. The result will be shown in content zone and will came from controller. you can also add an html widget with all controls you need and follow the same pattern...